# ModelSIM : debugging SIGNALs in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim

I am working in a VHDL code with a lot of SIGNALs that I should be able to see in the simulation on ModelSim to debug my design.

My question is whether is it necessary to declare outputs on my top-level entity so I can wire them an have access to those internal SIGNALs or is there any other way to access them from ModelSim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you can evaluate your design model interactively**

Can you use a waveform dump display to debug your design?  You can typically view any node in your design hierarchy.

**If you need algorithmic or programmatic access for verification**

Is your Modelsim -2008 compliant?  For validation purposes in a testbench or block that is not synthesized you can use external names.

See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 8.2 External names. You can access signals, variables and constants by providing a pathname. External names are also described in Peter Ashenden's and [Jim Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2367950/jim-lewis)'s book *VHDL 2008 Just the New Stuff*, Chapter 2.

**In Modelsim**

There's the *show* command which can access signals, processes, constants, variables, and entities. See the Modelsim Reference Manual, Commands, show.  Commands can be entered from the command line or in macro files.

Comment: Finally I discovered that it is possible to add signals directly from the VHDL code, editing it within ModelSim and right-clicking in the signal or variable we want to see. Then we need to "Add" and we will see it in the Waveform window.